# My if-else statement does not work, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: c++

Basically, I have a project due in about 2 days, and I cannot find how to make this `if else` statement work. I've done it before. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int response;
    cout << "is your circuit a parallel circuit?";

    if (response == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "yes";
    }
    else (response == 'N')
    {
        cout << "no";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know what this means:

[image]

Comment: First, `response` is an `int`, it contains a number. Second, you never ask for the user's input.

Comment: Where do you ask for input for `response`?  Also, if you expect `Y` or `N` as values, why is `response` and `int`?

Comment: It should be `else if`, not `else` (ignoring the other issues in the code).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int response;
> ```

If you want to read a character, `response` should be a `char` not an `int`.

> ```
> if (response == 'Y')
> ```

You forgot to actually read the user input. Your compiler should have warned you for using `response` uninitialized.

> ```
> else (response == 'N')
> ```

This is the cause of the error you get. `else` has no condition. `else` is the case for "none of the other conditions are `true`". You either want `else if` or no condition here.

Correct code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char response;
    std::cout << "is your circuit a parallel circuit?";
    std::cin >> response;
    if (response == 'Y') {     
        std::cout << "YES";
    } else if (response == 'N') {
        std::cout << "NO";
    } else {
        std::cout << "invalid input";
    }
}
```